# How to integrate mixpanel with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, mixpanel

In index.html I have added mixpanel code from https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript.

In my

```
export class MixpanelService {

  constructor() {
    mixpanel.init("sdfsdf", '', "development");
  }

  public track() {
    mixpanel.track('click', {pageName:'login'})
  }
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'mixpanel'.
   mixpanel.init("sdfsdf", '', "development");
```

Can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 14):

First, install mixpanel **for browser**. This is important.

```
npm install --save mixpanel-browser
```

Install the corresponding typings:

```
npm install --save @types/mixpanel
```

And add your trackingscript to index.html **without** `mixpanel.init()`:

```
<!-- start Mixpanel -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
    for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
</script>
<!-- end Mixpanel -->
```

---

I highly Recommend creating your own service, which can be very simple:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MixpanelService {

  /**
   * Initialize mixpanel.
   *
   * @param userToken
   */
  init(userToken: string): void {
    mixpanel.init('your-project-token');
    mixpanel.identify(userToken);
  }

  /**
   * Push new action to mixpanel.
   *
   * @param id Name of the action to track.
   * @param [action={}] Actions object with custom properties.
   */
  track(id: string, action: any = {}): void {
    mixpanel.track(id, action);
  }
}
```

*Note, I call the `init()` function from my userAuthService, but you can do whatever you want. Just make sure the `init()` is called before you start tracking.*

Then, from the rest of your code, you can use:

```
constructor(private mixpanelService: MixpanelService) { }

someFunction() {
  this.mixpanelService.track('Some action', {
    customPropertyOne: 'customValueOne',
    customPropertyTwo: 'customValueTwo'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example ..
I'm having issues with the line:
 
`import * as mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';`

I'm getting an error stating: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mixpanel-browser'`. I have installed via npm both mixpanel-browser and @types/mixpanel

Also, in your last function shouldn't you be calling "push" instead of "track" since I don't see "track" defined?

Comment: I just checked, and there is nothing in my answer that I forgot to tell/include.. It should work. I'm using Angular 6, with typescript 2.7.2. For `track`, yes it should really be track. It may not be defined, but it's definitely working.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, the line i'm referencing is in the `someFunction()` where you're calling track on the MixpanelService, maybe I am just confused! I will have to see why my mixpanel-browser is not being found.

Comment: Cheers, I guess my only difference is that im running Angular 5.2.9 ... very interesting that it cannot find the `mixpanel-browser` declaration file.

Comment: Why do you need to add the tracking snippet to the index.html if you install mixpanel-browser? I think installing the npm package and calling mixpanel.init() like you do in your service should be sufficient.

Comment: @benjiman My answer is almost 3 years old, so I can't really remember. But i *do* remember it didn't work without it. Maybe things have changed.. :)

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal No problem. For future reference: Now it works with just installing the SDK via npm. No tracking snippet required in index.js. If you want you can update your answer.

Comment: for install types of mixpanel, you should use this command

npm i --save-dev @types/mixpanel-browser

Answer (score 5):

- Install the Typings at global level which will help us to install the definations of the JS library.
  npm install -g typings
- Install the mixpaneljs 
  npm install mixpanel --save-dev
- run the below command to create the typing defincation into typings.json
  typings install dt~mixpanel --save --global

In your mixpanelService.ts file

```
import * as Mixpanel from "mixpanel";

this.mixpanel = Mixpanel.default.init(token, properties);
```

Comment: Hi @sumanth I'm wondering how you achieve this? I keep getting error TS2307: Cannot find module ...
I followed your instructions with no luck. I also opened an issue in the mixpanel lib (https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-js/issues/114)

Hope you can guide me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: hi @AgustinHaller - are you still facing the issue

Comment: Yes, I'm facing same issue /node_modules/@types/mixpanel/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Answer (score 4):

You have to include the mixpanel script in your index.html, but omit the

`mixpanel.init('token').`

Then in main.ts o app.component.ts you can declare the mixpanel library as variable:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
declare const mixpanel: any;

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

mixpanel.init(environment.mixpanel.apikey);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I use multiple Mixpanel projects to avoid mixing up the dev data with prod data.

Answer (score 0):

Another one good option is [angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2). It supports MixPanel and other tracking services.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this works.

If you are following the instructions provided by the Mixpanel.com page, you should paste the big snippet into your index.html of your aplication in between the "Head" tags.

Now, double check that the last part of the script, the mixpanel.init("TOKEN"); is replaced by the one you have in your project.
Make sure of this by clicking in the gear icon (In the report or <> page of Mixpanel) then click the tab "Management" and copy-paste the code of "Token" and then replace it from the one you copied in the index.html. If you are not the owner of the project, you can click on "Invite people" in the same location and then follow the same procedure.

Now, to track something, lets say, every time someone enters the landing page, you can paste this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     mixpanel.track("Page Loaded", { "Page Name": "Landing Page"});
    </script>
```

Between your "Body" tags.

Save all changes, load the web app (npm start / npm run / ng serve if you will)
and then go (or reload) the mixpanel.com page, click on the live view tab and there should be happening the magic.

Hope that works!