# How can I install separate mixpanel projects for development and production in angular5/angularitics

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mixpanel

I have already configured mixpanel in my angular 5 app. Now I want to separate mixpanel project for production and development. I have already added mixpanel script snippet in index.html in head section containing token of production project. Now I need to add another token and select one based upon selected environment, but environment variable is not accessible in index.html. I don't want to have two separate index.html in my project. In another way as suggested here ([How to integrate mixpanel with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249426/how-to-integrate-mixpanel-with-angular2/42479392#42479392)).I set token from main.ts, but it is unable to access environment variable.Is there any way to set token in index.html based upon selected environment?

I am getting following error:

ERROR in /home/Project/src/main.ts (9,27): Property 'mixpanel' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

**exported api key from environment.ts:**

export const mixpanel= {
  apikey: 'MY_PROJECT_TOKEN_HERE'
}

**main.ts**

```
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
    import { environment } from './environments/environment';
    declare const mixpanel: any;

    enableProdMode();        

    mixpanel.init(environment.mixpanel.apikey);
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: try using `environment['mixpanel']['apikey']`

Comment: Thank You @candidJ. It worked.!! :-)