# Integrate mixpannel with Angular 5

Tags: angular, mixpanel

I want to integrate mixpannel to my Angular app. I couldn't find a package or straight forward answer for this. Can anyone give me a link to good tutorial or code to integrate mixpannel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate mixpanel with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249426/how-to-integrate-mixpanel-with-angular2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

install mixpanel-browser

```
npm install --save mixpanel-browser
```

and types

```
npm install --save @types/mixpanel-browser
```

Add the tracking code to index.html

```html
    <!-- start Mixpanel -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!==typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
        for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===e.location.protocol&&"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
    </script>
    <!-- end Mixpanel -->
```

Add mixpanel token in environment files and create a wrapper service for Mixpanel events.

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from './environments/environment';
    import * as mixpanel from 'mixpanel-browser';
    
    
    @Injectable()
    export class MixpanelService {
      private mixpanelToken: string;
    
      /**
       * constructor
       * get mixpanel token and initialize
       */
      constructor() {
        this.mixpanelToken = environment.mixpanel_token;
    
        this.init();
      }
    
      /**
       * Initialize mixpanel.
       */
      init(): void {
        mixpanel.init(this.mixpanelToken);
      }
    
    
     /**
       * Create new Alias for user
       * Call this method only once in user lifecycle
       *
       * @param {string} alias
       */
      createAlias(alias: string) {
        mixpanel.alias(alias, mixpanel.get_distinct_id());
      }
    
      /**
       * Identify User
       *
       * @param {string} alias
       */
      identify(alias: string) {
        mixpanel.identify(alias);
      }
    
      /**
       * Push new action to mixpanel.
       *
       * @param {string} id Name of the action to track.
       * @param {*} [action={}] Actions object with custom properties.
       * @memberof MixpanelService
       */
      track(id: string, action: any = {}): void {
        mixpanel.track(id, action);
      }
    
      /**
       * setup mixpannel
       *
       */
      setup() {
        mixpanel.loggingEnabled = false;
        this.setSuperProperties({ Platform: 'web' });
      }
    
     /**
       * setPeople
       * Store user profiles in Mixpanel's People Analytics product
       * @param {Object} properties
       */
      setPeople(properties: any = {}): void {
        mixpanel.people.set(properties);
      }
    
      /**
       * setSuperProperties
       *
       * @param {object} properties
       */
      setSuperProperties(properties) {
        mixpanel.register(properties);
      }
    
      /**
       * sendEvent
       *
       * @param {string} event
       * @param {object} properties
       */
      sendEvent(event: string, properties?) {
        if (properties) {
          mixpanel.track(event, properties);
        } else {
          this.trackEvent(event);
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * trackEvent
       * @param {string} event
       */
      trackEvent(event: string) {
        mixpanel.track(event);
      }
    
      /**
       * Reset Mixpanel
       */
      logout() {
        mixpanel.reset();
      }
    
    }
```

Now use this mixpanel service any where.

```js
    constructor(private mixpanelService: MixpanelService) {}
    
    trackFunctionInComponent() {
      this.mixpanelService.track('Track action', {
        propertyOne: 'valueOne',
        propertyTwo: 'valueTwo'
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting such a complete and comprehensive answer! Very much appreciated. It worked for me in Angular 10. Cheers!